# Convert A Column In Pandas to One Long String (Python 3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert a pandas column into one long string?

For example, convert the following DF:

```
Keyword
James
Went
To
The
Market
```

To read as

```
Keyword
James went to the market
```

Any help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can first use `.tolist` to convert column to a list and then use `.join` method to concat all separate words together.

```
print(df)

  Keyword
0   James
1    Went
2      To
3     The
4  Market

' '.join(df['Keyword'].tolist())

# output: 'James Went To The Market'

# or to put them in a dataframe with 1 row 1 column
pd.DataFrame(' '.join(df['Keyword'].tolist()), columns=['Keyword'], index=[0])

                    Keyword
0  James Went To The Market
```

Answer (score 15):

You could use `str.cat` to join the strings in a column with a separator of your choice:

```
>>> df.Keyword.str.cat(sep=' ')
'James Went To The Market'
```

You can then put this string back into a DataFrame or Series.

Note: if you don't need *any* separator, you can simply use `df.sum()` (and you don't need to construct a new DataFrame afterwards).